# Operation about android start multiple activities at same time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When I try to do like following code:

```
public class A_activity extends activity {

.........

Intent B = new Intent(this, B_activity.class);

startActivity(B);// B_activity is a progress animation

......

sendBroadcast();// use to finish B_activity

Intent C = new Intent(this, C_activity.class);

startActivity(C);// C_activity is which should be start after B_activity

.........

}
```

It directly jumps into C_activity, but no B_activity. After I finish C_activity, B_activity startup. It's confusing to me, how can I clear the B_activity when I jump into C_activity, or make sure the B_activity start before C_activity?

In some reason, I must start them both in A_activity, and the time of startActivity(B) and startActivity(C) is not stable, maybe very short, like 100ms.

Comment: "the time between startActivity(B) and startActivity(C) is not stable, maybe very short,like 100ms."

Comment: If you start both activity then you will use Fragment!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Before answering your question...

Using activity to show progress indicator is a horrible idea. You should consider using AlertDialog instead of it.

#### Now the answer you want...

Unlike javascript, which is running in a single thread, when you say `startActivity(B)`, Android simply tells `ActivityManager` to start an Activity, but it won't block the main thread and continue to execute following codes, that's `startActivity(C)` in your case.

If you insist to use `B_activity` as progress indicator, you should implement `onActivityResult` in `A_activity`, and call `startActivity(C)` once `B_Activity` is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  When you call start activity, it starts immediately.  Either Activity B will need to start activity C, or you can start Activity C after Activity B finishes using startActivityForResult and onActvityResult.